# как сделать if not python

Tags: python

Есть допустим:

```
a1 = input()

if a1 не == 'Q':
   Действие

if a1 == 'Q':
   Действие
```

Человек например должен ввести в a1 букву 'Q'. Если он не ввёл эту букву то его перекидывает опять на a1. Если он ввёл правильную букву, то код идёт дальше.

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте так:

```
a1 = None

while a1 != 'Q':
    a1 = input("Введите букву,  'Q' - выход: ")

print("a1 = {}, идти дальше...".format(a1))
```

Comment: А как же код будет идти дальше? И разве нельзя сделать с if? Если после этого всего поставить print('123') то он не будет написан

Comment: @mikilikala представьте себе, что вы 10 раз ввели не ту букву, сколько if-ов вам надо написать ?

Comment: Ладно, давайте без if. А вот как сделать чтобы после введения Q дальше пошёл этот принт  print("идти дальше...")? Просто я проверил, и принт никак не работает.

Comment: @mikilikala плохо проверяли, все работает :)